# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set' (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to use tkinter (by following a tutorial, I am learning) to create a simple text editor.
Here is the code that I am having issues with:

```py
scroll = Scrollbar(stimulator_window).pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
Editor=Text(stimulator_window,width=400,height=450,yscrollcommand=scroll.set).pack(fill=BOTH)
scroll.config(command=Editor.yview)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Editor=Text(stimulator_window,width=400,height=450,yscrollcommand=scroll.set).pack(fill=BOTH)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

---

Python 3.10.3
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795]
VSCode

Comment: `scroll` is `None` because that is what `pack()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You meant to use two lines:

```py
scroll = Scrollbar(stimulator_window)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
```

Comment: Now this returns "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'yview'"

Comment: That's a new question, but it has the same answer.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a very popular question that should have closed as a duplicate

Comment: Ok, I'll close then.